# What are some famous examples of infant industries that failed?

Tags: international-trade, free-trade

The Japanese and Korean car and steel industries are often touted as examples of successful infant industries.

I'm trying to find some famous examples of failed infant industries. (They don't seem to show up easily on a quick Google search, so it would perhaps seem like there are not many such examples?)

Comment: For UK examples this Publication by the Institute of Economic Affairs (http://www.iea.org.uk/sites/default/files/publications/files/upldbook419pdf.pdf) may be helpful, although some of the examples are better described as projects than infant industries.

Comment: Why do the examples have to be famous? Almost all industries that fail in the very early days tend to be forgettable and largely forgotten.

Answer (score 2):

Malaysia's Proton cars (if you want a specific example ), but overall the Malaysia Automobile industry failed. Currently, only the locals drive Malaysian cars.

Answer (score 1):

I think Argentina has several failed infant industries, a good starting point is at the section Relative Lag on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_history_of_Argentina#Relative_lag).  A more specific example is when they tried nationalizing the railways from the British, as seen [in this article](http://cupola.gettysburg.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1053&context=ghj).

Answer (score 1):

The following is Table 2 from [The Infant Industry Argument: a Critical Scrutiny](http://arc.hhs.se/download.aspx?MediumId=1428):

[image]
J.M.H. Govers (2012)

> Therefore,  a  second  best  alternative  can  be  introduced  which 
>   examines  the  rate  of productivity   growth   of   the   protected industry   while   drawing   a   comparison   with  unprotected 
>   industries in  other  countries  (Bell  et  al.,  1984).  As  an 
>   alternative  one  can look  at  the  changes  in  productivity  levels
>   of  infants  during  a  period  of  protection.... The majority of the
>   firms presented however, show a modest productivity growth while being
>   under protection....A  rough  comparison  therefore  concludes  that 
>   only  a part   of   the   infant   industries   represented   in Table
>   2 experience   higher   levels   of productivity  growth  than  their 
>   mature  peers  abroad.

So, roughly speaking, the industries in this table with productivity changes below 5% can be thought of as infant industry failures and failures of industrial policy.

Answer (score 0):

> Some famous examples of failed infant industries

The nuclear fusion industry, despite more than half a century of trying through various technical fixes and subterfuges has failed to get anywhere. If it didn’t promise so much it surely would have been killed off by now.